# SQL Server permission types

Tags: sql-server, security

My team has recently moved into a more formalized system of SQL Server database auditing and deployment controls, and as a result several permissions have been restricted.

Many of us are not familiar with SQL Server security, and have encountered scenarios where we deploy something only to have a permissions restriction on, say, `TRUNCATE TABLE` denied in production.

It's just an annoyance at this stage, but I've tried to find some consolidated list (cheatsheet? cribsheet? reference lookup?) to easily check against for such functions so that it doesn't happen so easily, but I haven't found any.

I know that the MSN article for each function lists these, but I don't want to have to individually browse to the specific website for every common and rare function just to check, especially if I have to do it more than once because I forgot (for example).

The closest I found were sites like these:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1718/database-level-permissions-for-sql-server-2005-and-2008/

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-security-cribsheet/

...but they were incomplete (couldn't find TRUNCATE in both of them) and a little long: I'm hoping there's a table somewhere that simply put 'action -> action name -> permission name -> server/table level -> default role' or something  together in one place.

Is there such a list somewhere?

Comment: Actually stumbled on these almost after posting this article, but not via google (browsed around the mssqltips site). These are definitely helpful, but still don't cover table-level permissions so TRUNCATE is still missing...

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1714/server-level-permissions-for-sql-server-2005-and-sql-server-2008/

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1718/database-level-permissions-for-sql-server-2005-and-2008/

Comment: For deployment purposes, you should get a user account created with `db_owner` or `db_ddladmin` role and then use this account (through a deployment utility?) to deploy the database changes in production. This would also help with auditing and better deployment controls as there would only be one account doing deployments.

Comment: Not...quite what I meant. Taking truncating the table as an example, the action was supposed to be running in a stored procedure regularly, by (in this case) a user account that was not yet a `db_owner`.
The user that did the deployment was `db_owner`, but it wasn't the account that was to be running that SP. Since we coded as owners on our local databases the permission issue never arose so no one suspected anything until it got deployed and began to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I am not aware of any document that shows every action possible in SQL Server with the permissions required for it. Such a table would be impractical as there are a huge amount of possible actions, and some actions require multiple permissions, including scenarios where the permission requirements would change according to sub-portions of the action.

For the scenario you are trying to solve, it seems like you are using modules (SPs) to clearly define the actions allowed to the non-admin users, correct? In that case, you may be able to use digitally signed modules to grant the appropriate permissions when executing the SP instead of assigning the permission directly. For example:

```
CREATE USER [low_priv_user] WITHOUT LOGIN
go

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable](data int);
go

CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp_truncate_my_table]
AS
    TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[sp_truncate_my_table];
go

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[sp_truncate_my_table] TO [low_priv_user]
go

-- Will fail due to permission
EXECUTE ( 'EXEC [dbo].[sp_truncate_my_table];' )AS USER = 'low_priv_user';
go

-- Create a certificate to sign the SP,
CREATE CERTIFICATE [signing_cert] 
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<you_could_use_masetr_key_instead_of_p@55w0rD5>' 
    WITH SUBJECT = 'demo - module signature';
go
-- sign the SP
ADD SIGNATURE TO [dbo].[sp_truncate_my_table] BY CERTIFICATE [signing_cert] 
    WITH PASSWORD = '<you_could_use_masetr_key_instead_of_p@55w0rD5>';
go
-- destroy the private key
ALTER CERTIFICATE [signing_cert] REMOVE PRIVATE KEY;
go

-- Create a user for the certificate & grant it all the permissions you would need for running teh SP
CREATE USER [signing_cert] FROM CERTIFICATE [signing_cert];
go
GRANT ALTER ON [myTable] TO [signing_cert];
go

-- Permission check will be OK for the low privileged user
-- You control what this user is allowed to do via SPs
EXECUTE ( 'EXEC [dbo].[sp_truncate_my_table];' )AS USER = 'low_priv_user';
go
```

As you can see, I created a module that allows the caller to call `TRUNCATE` on a table, without granting `ALTER` permission directly to the user.

Ideally, when using this mechanism you would like to follow the least-privilege principle, and grant only the permissions you require and nothing else; but if you are having trouble finding the exact permissions you need, you may use a shortcut: `GRANT CONTROL TO [signing_cert]`.

Obviously such shortcut has significant security implications, as you are literally granting full control of your database to the signed code (including dynamic SQL executed within these modules), but if you decide to do it, I would recommend the following precautions:

- Destroy the private key to prevent anyone from abusing it
- Do not use dynamic SQL within your signed modules (or at least make sure you are not subject to SQL injection)
- If possible, avoid giving `CONTROL` permission on modules where you can grant the minimum privileges.
- Audit all activity on your database.

I am also including a copy of the [SQL Database Engine Permission Poster](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229142) link, which may be useful.

I hope this information helps.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't encountered using certificates before, but I think I can see what you mean. Your precautions are also very useful, thanks.

Comment: Also, the poster link is precisely what we need - though it still doesn't have `TRUNCATE`, it's got just about everything else. Our issue wasn't that we had problems granting the appropriate permissions where needed, but was more of not realizing which permissions were needed. In this example, we thought permissions for `TRUNCATE` was essentially the same as `DELETE`, and had granted them wrongly as a result.